# Gathering arrays from different processes in order

Tags: python, parallel-processing, mpi, mpi4py

I have several processes each computing some subarray. After they've finished I need to stitch the arrays together in order (ie: subarray 0, then subarray 1, then subarray 2, etc). The question: [Gathering small matrix portions from different processes with MPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19734358/gathering-small-matrix-portions-from-different-processes-with-mpi) has an answer involving looping through the processes and sending/recieving one at a time. However I don't believe the arrays will be stored in order as I require? Is there an alternative method  where the root process has a) each sub array and b) knowledge of which process it came from? Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any code to look at, this answer will be a little light on details. You can use MPI_ANY_SOURCE as the source argument for any MPI receive function, and then check "status.Get_source()" to find out who sent you a message. Lot's of examples of that [here](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/89111/mpi4py.MPI.ANY_SOURCE).